# What is the asymptotic formula of $\prod_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p \in\mathbb{P}, p\equiv k \mod m}}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right )$

Tags: number-theory

For fixed $k$ and $m$, I search for the asymptotic formula of:
$$n\to +\infty, \,\, \displaystyle\prod_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p \in\mathbb{P}, p\equiv k \mod m}}\left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{p} \right )$$

Comment: I have no idea what an "equivalente" is, but from PNT in arithmetic progressions it follows this product is asymptotically $C(\log n)^{-1/\varphi(m)}$ for some constant $C$ which depends on $k,m$.

Comment: It appears Williams has further determined the constant $C$ explicitly in https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/057.pdf

Comment: Using PNT for arithmetic progressions, we have $\pi_{m,k}(x)\sim\dfrac{1}{\varphi(m)}\dfrac{x}{\log(x)}$, where $\pi_{m,k}(x)=\#\{p\in\mathbb{P} \, | \, p \equiv k \bmod m \, , \, p \leq x\}$, @Wojowu can you explain how you get your result ?

Comment: Take logarithm of your product and use [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula).

Comment: @Wojowu (for $\gcd(k,m)=1$) the constant is something like  $$C_k\lim_{s \to 1} \frac{\zeta(s)^{1/\varphi(m)}}{\zeta_{k \bmod m}(s)} = C_k\prod_{\chi \bmod m, \chi \ne 1_{\gcd(n,m)=1}} L(1,\chi)^{-\overline{\chi(k)}/\varphi(m) }$$ where $C_k = (e^{\gamma} \prod_{p | m} (1-p^{-1})^{1/\varphi(m)}$

Comment: Those kind of things are the topic of the proof of the PNT plus of the Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions (which leads to the PNT in arithmetic progressions), the main idea being that of Dirichlet L-functions keeping most of the properties of $\zeta(s)$. Note sure if there is an equivalent of Mertens theorem for that product (ie. not needing a proof of the PNT in arithmetic progressions) @Lagrida

Comment: Thank you of yours contributions